# General solutions to replace string regex preceded and followed by '\n'

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a file in CentOS which looks like following

```
[root@localhost nn]# cat -A excel.log
real1$
0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I$
real2$
0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I$
real3$
0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I$
real4$
0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I$
real5$
0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I1^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I0.5^I$
real6$
```

I would like to replace `\nreal[2-6]\n` with `\t\t\t'` and have tried unsuccessfully the following

```
sed -i 's/\nreal[2-6]\n/\t\t\t/g' file
```

It seems that sed has difficulty to deal with line break. Any idea to fulfill the regex in CentOS?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Try `sed -i -z 's/\nreal[2-6]\n/\t\t\t/g' file` if the `sed` is GNU sed.

Comment: It seems working for real[2-6], but not working for (512|513)real.

Comment: To be specific, if I want to replace '\n(512|513)real\n' with '\t\t\t', then it won't work.

Comment: `sed -i -Ez 's/\n(512|513)real\n/\t\t\t/g' file`? `sed -i -rz 's/\n(512|513)real\n/\t\t\t/g' file`? `sed -i -z 's/\n51[23]real\n/\t\t\t/g' file`? What is the right answer for you here? What is your goal?

Comment: I posted the [`sed` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623384/3832970).

Comment: My goal is that a general regex (i.e. real[2-6] or (512|513)real, specifically in my current file) preceded and followed by '\n' are replaced by '\t\t\t' (or a general regex) with sed.

Comment: Your solution seems to use '?' to join multiple sed, which I don't know if it works.

Comment: I have 3 questions with code inside in the comment + 2 additional questions without code. There are not "multiple seds".

Comment: The OR regex is `\n(51[23]real|real[2-6])\n` not the one from the answer selected.

Comment: @Maxt8r: It is because requirements were different originally. Have updated now. Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try `sed -i -Ez 's/\n(51[23]real|real[2-6])\n/\t\t\t/g' file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to consider `perl` then use:

```sh
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/\n(?:51[23]real|real[2-6])(?:\n|\z)/\t\t\t/g' file
```

If you want to avoid last `real\d+` line to be replaced with `\t\t\t` then use:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/\n(?:51[23]real|real[2-6])\n(?!\z)/\t\t\t/g' file
```

`(?!\z)` is negative lookahead to fail the match when we have line end just ahead of us.

Comment: This solution works for '\n(512|513)real\n'.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand. `\nreal[2-6]\n` is regex which will not match `\n(512|513)real\n`

Comment: If you also want to match 512 or 513 before real then please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed`, you need to use the `-z` option:

```sh
sed -i -z 's/\nreal[2-6]\n/\t\t\t/g' file
#      ^^
```

Now, that you also want to handle specific alternations, you need to enable the POSIX ERE syntax, either with `-r` or `-E` option:

```sh
sed -i -Ez 's/\n(51[23]real|real[2-6])\n/\t\t\t/g' file
```